# json.net insert multiple objects on post

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hi I want to store multiple posts of jsonCallback. As it is my script works but overwrites/updates bw_results.json each time.

```
 string json = "jsonCallback(\n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented) + "\n);";

    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JSON\dotNet_BW3b\bw_results.json", json);
```

// And this my json file

```
    jsonCallback(
{
  "bw_numbers": [
    "76",
    "66",
    "44",
    "66",
    "66",
    "65"
  ],
  "coin": "H",
  "bw_draw": "7890",
  "bw_date": "Jun 07, 2013"
}
);
```

So question is how do i insert multiple jsonCallback posts?

Many Thanks Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code to add multiple jsonCallback posts to avoid override:

```
string path = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JSON\dotNet_BW3b\bw_results.json";

if (!File.Exists(path)) 
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, json);    
}
else
{
    File.AppendAllText(path, json);    
}
```